# What is the standard for testing php phalcon api endpoints?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phalcon, web-api-testing

When testing an API endpoint is there a way to make the HTTP request to a test server started by the testing framework(PHPUnit) maybe building a specific database just for testing?

What I find online is a bit strange. It implies to make a request to an already running server using `phalcon/incubator`

Here is what I found online: https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/1475/-solved-unittest-on-my-api-project

I am curious if this approach of using an already running server is common in PHP.

If possible can you point me to some repositories with examples of php phalcon tests.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using **Travis CI** to deploy a clean instance and installing all dependencies (Phalcon, MySQL, Redis etc) and seeding the newly created database. For testing api endpoints we rely on the **CodeCeption Framework** for api tests, json-schema validation etc.